# Connecting Android Studio to Firebase for Authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I can't seem to connect to firebase authentication with register people with the following code. I followed the instructions on the Android Studio help for firebase authentication. I added this line in the Gradle too:
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    username = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.username));
    password = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.password));
    signIn = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.signIn));
    register = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.register));
}

private void registerUser()
{
    loginUsernameString = username.getText().toString();
    loginPasswordString = password.getText().toString();

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(loginUsernameString, loginPasswordString)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Failed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if (view == signIn)
        registerUser();
}
```

Comment: Does it show "Failed" toast ? Did you debug the method to see if it works when you press the button ?

Comment: It does pass through to the registerUser method but returns this: 03-12 15:18:10.039 11566-11566/com.example.viraj.swimapp D/LoginActivity: createUserWithEmail:onComplete:false
which I'm guessing it means it didn't make a connection with firebase.

Comment: Use this `Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Failed=" + task.getException().getMessage());` to see why it's failing. Could be a number of reasons like password not strong enough

Comment: Ok I used that line. This is what I get 'Failed=An internal error has occurred. [ Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 1000819886041 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https ] '

Comment: I got it, you have to go to this link to enable it. Thanks. for the help

Comment: did you enabled the auth with email from firebase console ?

Comment: I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, the entire authentication process using **[Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=5)** and **[Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIRt9Ts0fRU&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=6)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get your user with `mAuth`, if `mAuth` returns null there is a problem authenticating your user

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginUsernameString, loginPasswordString)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    Log.d(userCreated, ""+user);
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }

                // ...
            }
        });
```

make sure tu have the latest compile in your gradle which is this at the moment

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
```

make sure you enable in your `firebase console` the option for authenticating your users

[image]

Hope it helps

Happy coding !

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working now. Also do I need to update the line compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0' everyday or every week?

Comment: No, the gradle will tell you when to update it , but don't worry, if the answer helped you feel free to accept it as an answer , so others can see that it helped you and maybe help them too :)